# Using Javascript to load dropdown values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have following code where I am trying to load values into a dropdown from an array(from file page students.js):

student.js

```
var STU_NAME = 0;
var STU_ID = 1;
var STU_AGE = 2;
var STUDENTS = [
    ["Apple", 1, 15],
    ["Billy", 2, 16]
    ["Cathy", 3, 14]        
        ];
```

Functions.js

```
var jQ = $.noConflict();

function populateStudents() {
    jQ('#students').empty();
    jQ('#students').append(jQ("<option></option>").attr("value", "").text("-- Please Select --"));
    for (var _i = 0; _i < students.length; _i++) {
        jQ('#students').append(jQ("<option></option>").attr("value", _i).text(STUDENTS[_i][STU_NAME]));
    }
}

jQ(document).ready(function () {
    populateStudents();
});
```

mypage.aspx

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="model">
        <form>
        <div>
            <div id="StudentLabel">
                Student:
            </div>
            <select id="students" name="students">
            </select>
        </div>      
        <script src="../Scripts/Functions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="../Scripts/student.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I get an error "Microsoft JScript runtime error: '$' is undefined" at line 1 of Functions.js

Can anyone help me on what I would be missing to make it working here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`You need to include jquery library`, you can download from [here](http://jquery.com/download/) Add the script tag in head of page or before you use jquery.

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">

    </style>
   <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/Functions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/student.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: That was so foolish of me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You have forgotten to add the jquery library

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/Functions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/student.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

It is highly recommended to use CDN version of jquery to improve pagespeed,**[check this link](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#cdn)**